# Apache: .htaccess ErrorDocument up one level?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, error-handling

my site structure like this:

```
- pages
    404.php
    403.php
- app
    /css
    /-script
    index.php
    .htaccess
```

in my .htaccess

if I type `ErrorDocument 403 /403.php`

and put 403.php inside /app and it works

but I need to do something like `ErrorDocument 403 ../pages/403.php`

how can I achieve that?

Comment: did `../403.php` not work ?

Comment: no,just show "../403.php" in the web page

Comment: and did you try using absolute path ?

Comment: Your .htacces should be on your root

Comment: could you solve this? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is not possible. In order to retrieve a document above the root, you would need to create a script that fetches it's content.

The `ErrorDocument` instruction can only see below it's location, not above.

So, if you were to create an `error.php` file in the `app` directory that fetches the file from the `pages` directory (according to the parameter `?error=404`), it would work.

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?error=404

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to place the .htaccess file a folder up.
.htaccess files are being read (and "used") for any folder "under" the .htaccess as long there is not one in the specific folder "overriding" the .htaccess most upward.

All this depends on your setup, though. (DocumentRoot, etc.)